# Using Python strip and split functions in ArcGIS Field Calculator?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, field-calculator, python-parser

I am trying to populate a field with the last word in an address string using field calculator within ModelBuilder.  My code takes the whole address string (1234 S Brittany Town Dr) as a parameter, then splits it into a list and returns the last item in the list:

```
def getSufDir( prop_location ):
    prop_location.strip()
    x = prop_location.split(' ')
    return x[len(x)-1]
```

This code works for 433 of the 37,000 records in the layer.  I discovered that those 433 records have 25 characters (prop_location is a 25 character maximum field).  All other records return blank.  Why is this happening?  These code snippets seem to work fine in IDLE, but return blank values for most records when done in Field Calculator.  I have attached an image of my field calculator window for reference.

[image]

An example of an address that is failing to process is 6847 W Mesa Arch Dr.

I edited to code to:

```
return x[-1]
```

and got an identical result.

Comment: What happens if you use 'return x[-1]'? This will also return the last item in the list.

Comment: An example of an address that is failing to process is 6847 W Mesa Arch Dr.  I edited to code to 'return x[-1]' and got an identical result.  Thank you both for your responses.

Comment: try creating a new variable as the result of the strip() method.  so `s = prop_location.strip()` and then proceed by using `s`.  strip does not modify the object (like sort() does with a list) but it returns a new object.

Comment: x[-1] should do the job. also check if records are within environment spatial extent

Comment: Is it possible that the field is filled with spaces at the end of the string?  And the blank it is returning is just a space?  The 433 rows that are a full 25 characters wouldn't have spaces at the end of the string.

Comment: I think @mr.adam's comment will solve your problem. Further I would advise using `prop_location.strip().split(" ")[-1]` in the Expression without bothering the Code Block.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button to provide any requested clarifications.

Comment: Thank you to all who offered input.  mr.adam and fatih_dur, your responses were especially helpful.  I have posted the working code in an answer (is that how I was supposed to do it?).  There are 72 records that instead of returning DR, or ST, return #301 or A because the apartment is at the end.  Some strings have #301, others have # A.  I need to code it so that if the final item in the list contains #, return the second to last item, and if the second to last item contains #, return the third to last item.  Shall I pose this as a separate question?

Answer (score 1):

There were some records that were blank which caused an error.  This code works:

```
def getSufDir( prop_location ):
if prop_location is None:
    return None
else:
    return prop_location.strip().split(" ")[-1]
```

Comment: Just a style comment, you don't need to specify a space in split(); a space is the default.